# Provide WMS Service through QGIS Server

Tags: wms, qgis-server

I'm trying to figure out how to provide WMS - Services with QGIS and in my Research I encountered QGIS Server.

But I'm still uncertain about how it actually works. I install Apache Webserver and make the configurations like in the tutorial https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html

Than I open my QGIS Project-> Project Settings -> QGIS Server and in the following window I make all the necessary Settings.

What I should get is a WMS URL like "https://localhost/cgi-bin?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"   right?

But my client can't Import this WMS Service yet or can he? I think the moment I turn off my computer he won't have access to the URL anymore right? My Question is, after installing QGIS Server and creating a get capabilities request, what else do I need to do so that the URL is permanently available for users with permission.

Comment: Installing on a personal computer is only for training/testing purpose so you can understand how it work and how to configure thing. That's not the way to go if you want to give access over the web (you will need to host your data and QGIS server somewhere where people could access over the web)

Comment: So I would need to buy a host and than I could upload QGIS Server and the WMS URL to this host and than its accessible over the Internet.

Comment: Yes you will need hosting with QGIS server and some kind of database installed on it